# Can generic Swift class inherit NSStreamDelegate and be usable as real Objective-C stream delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, generics

With all this new mix and max between Objective-C and Swift I have a problem when trying to open TCP connection and provide generic Swift class as delegate to the stream. The class never receives any events, such as stream opened or space available. The server side detects the successful connect thou.
My class is something like that:

```
class TcpPoint<StreamType: NSStream> : NSObject, NSStreamDelegate {
    func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent) {
        assert(false, "stream event")
    }
}
```

this class is set as NSOutputStream/NSInputStream delegate and the stream are scheduled and opened.

I've read in the Apple Dev docs that generics cannot be used from Objective-C (which is logical since Objective-C doesn't support generics) and I'm guessing because the delegate protocol is ObjC and because the NSInput/OutputStream is also ObjC, they can't use my function and the message is lost.

Am I on the right way? I have a lot of XP in C++ dev but I'm pretty new to the iOS.

Comment: Why do you define TcpPoint as a generic class? Does it work if you omit the `<StreamType: NSStream>` ?

Comment: I'm wrapping input and output streams into different classes, in order to manage them without too many logic forks (if's). Because most of the implementation in the both classes will be the same I want to extract it in base class which have to be generic in order to have member stream (which will be input or output), which is needed to handle few tasks which are common, like errors, encounter end situations and etc.

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar problem trying to use a generic swift class as a data source for a UIPickerView and I get an unrecognized selector error. Did you manage to solve this? Thanks.